# How to change the BING SpellCheck of the LuisService at runtime?

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding, bing-api

I'm trying to include the BING SpellChecker in my LUIS-App.
It's working fine, but I would like to change the bool SpellChecker of my current LuisService at runtime. 
The idea: Only use the spell checker if LUIS gets the intent 'NONE' with the original query and tries it again with the altered query.

Therefore, I need to change the variable at runtime and post a new request. Is this possible?

This is my constructor of the LuisDialog:

```
public BasicLuisDialog() : base(new LuisService(new LuisModelAttribute(
        LUIS_appId,
        LUIS_apiKey,
        domain: LUIS_hostRegion
        )
    {
        Verbose = true,
        BingSpellCheckSubscriptionKey = BING_key,
        SpellCheck = true
    }))
    {
    }
```

Thank you and best regards
Bahneby

Answer (score 0):

So, looking at the [Programmatic LUIS API doc](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c2f), it really doesn't look like there's a way to edit your LUIS model programmatically directly to include/exclude Bing Spell Check.

---

However, that being said maybe you could go about designing your program to actually call the Bing Spell Check from your bot instead of having LUIS take care of it.

Psuedocode would be:

1. Get utterance from the text of the message that user sends your bot (**no spell check**)
2. **Send utterance to LUIS**
3. If LUIS result shows that the **intent** is **None** => in the method that handles None intent, take message and **"filter" it through the Bing Spell Check API**
4. **Call LUIS again** from the None intent handler, **using the spell-checked utterance** that you got from the Bing Spell Check API

And you could check for examples of how to make a call to the Bing Spell Check API from their documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-spell-check/) in various languages.

---

EDIT: 
Just noticed the endpoint called in the LUIS ai portal if you enable spell check

For step 3 & 4 in the pseudocode above, you could probably just combine them by editing the endpoint that your bot calls in your 2nd call to LUIS from the None intent handler inside your bot.

Just change the url parameter `spellCheck=true` (and in your original call to LUIS,  you could have spellCheck=false`)

Example endpoint URL:

`https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/LUIS_APP_ID?spellCheck=true&bing-spell-check-subscription-key=%7BYOUR_BING_KEY_HERE%7D&verbose=true&timezoneOffset=-360&subscription-key=LUIS_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY&q=`